# Fix UIImagePickerController to portrait orientation

Tags: ios

I have a UIImagePickerController added to my view in this way:

```
- (IBAction)TakeCameraShot:(id)sender{

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{

    // Given by default your orientation is in landscaperight already
    while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


   /* picker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    picker.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;*/
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

   /* picker.view.layer.cornerRadius = 150;
    picker.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(12, 60, 296, 290);*/

}else{
    NSLog(@"Camera is not available");
    UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Important message" message:@"Unfortunately the camera is not available on your device." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert1 show];
}
}
```

I am trying to prevent it from being rotated to landscape with this code

```
// Given by default your orientation is in landscaperight already
    while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

The answer of stack overflow provided also said that it would only work if the UIviewController was already set to portrait only, so this is what I did from the general app settings (where you choose ipad, iphone, or universal). But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This Code will work on Ipad i used it but you need to add this

```
while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

After presenting `UIImagePickerController` too ---

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

     while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

while ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
     [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

This will also going to work on ipod ,but on ipod it still gives you rotated image ,if you want a potrait image in ipod always , you need to change their orientation like this

UIImageOrientationRight -- This orientation is when image is clicked when camera is in potrait
   UIImageOrientationUp -- This when camera in landscape left

UIImageOrientationDown -- This is when camera is landscape right

UIImageOrientationLeft -- this is when camera is potraitupside down

now in all other three conditions other than first than change image orientation to UIImageOrientationRight .

This can be done by just checking orientation of coming image and apply new orientation .

Comment: are you using overlay

Comment: try now sir, i changed first while position , are you checking it on ipad

Comment: Actually I was testing it out on the ipod touch, but yes I will need it on both iOS devices

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on ipod touch (the device is running ios7). The icons still rotate when the device is rotated

Comment: i am running this code on ios 6 actually , let me check this on ios 7 , i'll get back to you with this soon.sorry for delay

Answer (score 0):

just create a category for UIImagePickerController and put this line of code in that class

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
  return NO;
  }